# How to query for objects stored in an array in a mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following nested object stored in my mongoDB:

```
var Appointment = new Schema ({

    students: [{user1:String,user2:String, _id: false}],
});
```

I now want to query my appointments for a studentName which is stored in the array students either in user1 or user2. But I have no idea how I could achieve that?
If it is an array I would use:

```
    Appointment.find({
        students: {$in: [studentName]}
    }, function(err, appointmentsDb) {
        // do something
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/#op._S_or) operator and dot notation for this:

```
Appointment.find({ $or: [
    { 'students.user1': studentName },
    { 'students.user2': studentName }
]}, callback);
```